# Hyperlink is not opened in Excel 2010 on click

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2010

When I click on hyperlink in Excel 2010, nothing happens.
How to make web-browser open on click?

It seems something specific with Excel only, because links in Outlook works fine.

I have found description of issues in Internet when after click on link, some message appears. But in my case no message - on click nothing happens.

This on my Windows Vista x32 PC, and I installed MS Office 2010 over MS Office 2003 with a lot of trubles.
On my other Windows 7 x86 PC, where I installed Office 2010 not over other version of MS office. Possibly this is a source of issue?

Comment: You say "some message appears". Can you share the message with us so we can help you? Also, how is the hyperlink created in the cell? Is it an actual hyperlink (mouse pointer turns to hand when you hover over it) or just text (no hand)? Please [edit] your question with more details. Maybe even a screen shot of the hyperlink?

Comment: No message - I clarified question, sorry. Link is created via link button, it works fine on othe PC.